# How to force recompile of execution plan of a Linq to SQL query?

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql, sql-execution-plan

I have a LINQ to SQL query that's created dynamically. Funny thing is, when I run it in SQL Management Studio it's lightning fast. When I run it from L2S it becomes awefully slow after a while.

This is probably because of the query plan/execution plan. When I restart SQL Server the L2S query is also lightning fast again.

Now with T-SQL you can have WITH RECOMPILE. But how to do this with L2S?

Comment: In 99% of cases, you should not need WITH RECOMPILE; it is usually a symptom you are treating, rather than the real cause...

Comment: It is a symptom of parameter sniffing being imperfect and sometimes resulting in crazy decisions. If it were programmer error, all queries would be slow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I found in the thread below, you can use the `DataContext.GetCommand(IQueryable)` to get a `DbCommand` for the query you wish to execute.  You can add "OPTION (RECOMPILE)" to the command text, from that, open a reader, and use `[DataContext.Translate<T>`][1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.datacontext.translate) to translate the opened reader to the entity type you wanted.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqtosql/thread/def80609-eaf2-4631-8d3d-ad10fc9aedfa

For example, given a `DataContext dataContext`:

```
IQueryable<string> exampleItemsQuery = dataContext.Table.Where(…).Select(…); //etc

DbCommand command = dataContext.GetCommand(exampleItemsQuery);
command.CommandText += Environment.NewLine + "OPTION (RECOMPILE)";
if (dataContext.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
   dataContext.Connection.Open();

IEnumerable<string> exampleItems = dataContext.Translate<string>(command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection));
```

Comment: However it doesn't seem to work with some load options. The DataContext.Translate<T> may start executing another SQL command and fail since the current command still uses the connection.

Comment: I sort of understand what you are saying, but a clear example of how to do this would be greatly helpful

Answer (score 2):

From the behaviour you describe, your statistics are almost certainly out of date.

I suggest you rebuild them:

```
exec sp_MSForeachTable 'UPDATE STATISTICS ?'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [CompiledQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.compiledquery.aspx) class. Here's a [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399335(VS.100).aspx) from Microsoft that goes into even more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I used this [EF 6 Parameter Sniffing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25145667/ef-6-parameter-sniffing/25147157#25147157) to add at the end of SQL commands "option(recompile)" before executing. It work for me. It is very good workaround how to solve it.